# accessing specific columns of a dataframe, index specified by idxmax()

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe row that I would like to access specific columns of. The index for this row is specified from a idxmax command.

```
    idx_interest=(df['colA']==matchingstring).idxmax()
```

Using this index, I want to access specific columns, namely colB and colD of the df @ index=idx_interest

```
    df.loc[idx_interest,['colB','colD']].reset_index().values.tolist()
```

however, doing so gave me the error: cannot perform reduce on flexible type. How do I go about accessing columns of a df @ index given from an idxmax command>

Comment: What is `x`?  Do you mean to use `df` there?  Actually, your bigger issue is that you wrote `df['colA'==...` where it should be `df['colA']==...`.  Close the bracket.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I have fixed the errors accordingly.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `df.loc[idx_interest]['colB','colD'].reset_index().values.tolist()`?

Comment: Still looks wrong.  Closing bracket should be outside quote.  Is this what your actual code looks like?  @ Joe Patten - his code (other than the typos) should work.  The use of `.loc` is correct.

Comment: Can you show us what `idx_interest` returns?

Comment: idx_interest returns an integer, in my dataframe it happened to be 1023

Comment: I can't reproduce your error. Please supply a **[mcve]**.

Answer (score 0):

You need to first apply your filter to your dataframe `df` correctly, in order to return `idx_interest`. If your original dataframe is a MultiIndex, then be mindful that this will return a tuple:

```
idx_interest = df[df['colA']==matchingstring].idxmax()
```

Now that you have `idx_interest`, you can limit your dataframe to the columns you want and then call `.iloc()` to specify a row index:

```
df[['colB','colD']].iloc[idx_interest].values.tolist()
```

The code you provide above will also work assuming that `idx_interest` returns an `int`:

```
df.loc[idx_interest,['colB','colD']].reset_index().values.tolist()
```

Comment: `df.loc[idx_interest,['colB','colD']].reset_index().values.tolist()` works perfectly fine for me. Are you sure there's something wrong with OP's syntax?

Comment: Agreed that will also work. I've updated my answer accordingly. My hunch is that the OP's assignment of `idx_interest` is the root of the issue.